# Assign groups by total sum using R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have plate_df that makes a pattern of a 96 well plate in column format A1, B1, C1, etc. and a dataframe df2 that has different values in the quantity column.
I am having trouble adding well assignments from plate_df to a new column in df2 that will group those quantities of df2 into groups of 100 until all the quantities have been assigned a well. The dummy data has a pattern, but please treat it like the quantities are random.

```
#Make pattern for target well assignments 
rowsPlate <- c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H")
columnsPlate <- seq(from = 1, to = 12, by = 1)

wells <- NULL

for (col in columnsPlate){    
 wells <- c(wells, paste0(rowsPlate, col))  
}

#Make df2
plate_df <- data.frame(wells)

df2 <- data.frame(index=seq(1,96, by=1), quantity = sample(0.1:20,8, replace = TRUE))
```

[image: Looking for something like this]

Comment: Your code produces 144 unique well IDs, but your expected output shows the same IDs repeating multiple times. How do you intend to arrive at the expected output? Your post is unclear.

Comment: Apologies, that should read "96 unique well IDs".

Comment: plate_df produces 96 unique well assignments. I need to pool/assign the samples in df2 to a well assignment in quantities of 100. In the example picture, you can see that the index 1-13 add up to as close to 100 without exceeding, so they are assigned with well A1. The next batch of index that sum as close to 100 without exceeding are assigned with B1, and so on. I am having trouble making code that bins all of the rows in this way until all the rows of df2 are assigned a well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can calculate a rolling sum of your "quantities" column, then divide this by 100, always rounding up to the nearest whole number. We can then use this numbering as an index into the `wells` vector to create the labeling. But be sure that you have enough labels in `wells` to handle all the bins.

```
# create labels
rowsPlate <- LETTERS[1:8]
columnsPlate <- 1:12
wells <- c(outer(rowsPlate, columnsPlate, paste0))

#Make df2
df2 <- data.frame(index=seq(1,96, by=1), quantity = sample(0.1:20,8, replace = TRUE))


library(tidyverse)

# example output
df3 <- df2 %>% 
  mutate(
    quantity_running = cumsum(quantity),
    bin = ceiling(quantity_running / 100),
    well = wells[bin]
  )

   index quantity quantity_running bin  well
1      1     11.1             11.1   1    A1
2      2     14.1             25.2   1    A1
3      3      9.1             34.3   1    A1
4      4     12.1             46.4   1    A1
5      5      6.1             52.5   1    A1
6      6      8.1             60.6   1    A1
7      7      8.1             68.7   1    A1
8      8      9.1             77.8   1    A1
9      9     11.1             88.9   1    A1
10    10     14.1            103.0   2    B1
11    11      9.1            112.1   2    B1
12    12     12.1            124.2   2    B1
13    13      6.1            130.3   2    B1
14    14      8.1            138.4   2    B1
15    15      8.1            146.5   2    B1
16    16      9.1            155.6   2    B1
17    17     11.1            166.7   2    B1
18    18     14.1            180.8   2    B1
19    19      9.1            189.9   2    B1
```